# "used to" and "had"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-meaning

Could someone explain whether the following sentences have different meanings?

> "Lisa used to have long hair when she was a child"
>
> "Lisa had long hair when she was a child"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context, they could mean the same thing or two separate things. 
For starters, "used to" usually implies the imperfect tense in most Romance languages (if that should be what you speak) whereas "had" is usually the simple past in English.  "Used to" gives the feeling that Lisa had long hair over a long period of time, perhaps her whole childhood or most of her childhood, whereas "had" in your second example can mean that there was one time or perhaps a few instances during her childhood that Lisa had long hair, but they were few and far between.  In French, the imperfect would be used here because, chances are, this wasn't a one-off, that is, a one-time occurrence:

> "Elle **avait** les cheveux longs quand elle était enfant." ("She used to have long hair when she was a child.")

However, in English, depending on the context, "had" can be used as the simple past and imperfect in this situation, but "used to" denotes the imperfectness in English; no contextualization is needed.

Comment: # Nicholas. Thank you very much. Well, still I am not so familiar when can I use "used to", "had" or just past simple. I cannot use correct a word in the following situation also.  Imagine I am a teacher. Five years ago I taught the subject A and since then I have not been teaching that subject (I have been teaching other subjects). In this situation can I say

"I used to teach the subject A five year ago" or should I use past simple "I taught the subject A five year ago"

Comment: Well "had" is the past simple. What language is your mother tongue? In your examples, both are fine and mean the same thing in English; however, most people would use the second one with the past simple since you have stated a specific time: "Oh really, I used to teach English. In fact, I taught it five years ago, but I had to stop teaching it because of personal reasons."

Comment: "Yes, I **used to teach** English." "Really, when **did you use to teach** it?" "I **used to teach it (or taught it)** 5 years ago. In fact, I **was teaching** English when I got sick. After I had recovered from my ailment, I decided to retire from teaching English. I can't believe it was five years ago that I last **taught** English. Do you know that I **had been teaching** English for 40 years when I got sick and had to retire?" In the above, "was teaching" and "used to teach" both create the imperfect tense in English and would translate into the imperfect in Romance languages.

Comment: When asking it in a question, you could say, "When **used** you **to** teach it?" since it is a semi-modal in English; however, it is considered archaic these days and 99.99% of people will ask it with a "did" as if it were a form of the simple past tense.

Comment: Thank you so much for a nice explanation. Appreciate it.

Comment: I always use Past Simple for past possesions and **used to** for past habits. So, "**I had curly hair when I was a child**" and "**I used to attend an English club when I was young**"

Comment: "**I used to have curly hair when I was a child**" really sounds odd.

Comment: That's fine, Alexander. You could also say, "I **used to have** curly hair when I was a child" and "I **attended** an English club when I was young." However, using **attended** there can be confusing unless the person should know the context behind it. By using **used to**, the person knows this was over a period of time and not a one-off.

Comment: You may think it sounds odd, but, to me, it sounds fine. I've heard it said many times; however, "I had curly hair is fine" also.  They are both fine.

Comment: Here's an example on YouTube of a song called, "I used to have a best friend, but then he gave me an STD."https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPsqm6NN5SI

Answer (score 2):

The difference between these phrases is that **used to** is a modal verb and **had** is only in simple past.

The first phrase uses **used to** that is a modal verb:

> "Lisa **used to** have long hair when she was a child"

These means that the action was a routine in the past or happened many times in a time frame, so if you want to say a action that happened in the past **but** it happened frequently or happened between a time frame, you should use the modal verb **used to**

The second phrase only uses **had** so is in simple past:

> "Lisa **had** long hair when she was a child"

These means that the action was in the past **but** only for once.
[image: Timeline]

Here I try to explain the difference, in the **red hand** we have the simple past, which is used to say an action that happend in the past. The **blue hands** point to two different points of the timeline that is the action happened between these dates.

Comment: I agree with you regarding most of this, alex; however, for starters, "used to" is a semi-modal; not a modal. Second, in English, "had" can be used in the imperfect with the same meaning as "used to have" depending upon the context. I shall agree with this: it is better to say "used to have" because it lets the person know that it was happening over a period of time. In English, they both can mean the same thing when contextualized.

Comment: **Example:** "Oh, you have a beautiful doll there, sweetie. I **had (or used to have)** the same doll when I was young. I **would (or used to)** play with her all of the time. She **was (or used to be)** my favorite doll, too."

Comment: Not exactly, Past Simple can refer to the whole of the past, a defined time interval or to a certain point in the past whereas "**used to**" in the past can refer only to a time interval.

Comment: Hahaha Well I guess you have the reason, with the correct context you can say the same meaning with different words, but in other languages (spanish for example) the usage of **a** (only one) word or phrase without context can change it completely. Thank you for the help to clarify it. :)

Comment: English is more flexible than Spanish or French or any other Romance language in this respect because it doesn't have a true imperfect tense. These would take the imperfect in other languages whereas English has different forms that construct an imperfect. This is similar to the constructions used to create the future tense since English technically doesn't have a future tense conjugation; it just has a future tense construction.

Comment: With a verb that denotes a simple action or event, the simple past refers to a point in time ("he kissed her").  But with a verb that is *stative*, the simple past often refers to a long period.  This is also connected with the fact that we can't say "I was having a cat" - we have to choose between "I had a cat" and "I used to have a cat".  (But even with an action verb, if you said "I played with the doll when I was younger", no one would assume you were necessarily referring to an isolated occasion.)

Comment: I agree, rjpond. In French, "I used to have a cat" would take the imperfect; however, in English, one can play with the simple past and the semi-modal "used to": *"J'avais un chat quand j'étais jeune."*